# Xcode Objective-C Mac: How to place object on top of AVPlayerView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, avplayerview

I'm currently working on a game. It plays a movie and the story changes depending on the players actions. I'm using quick time events (press a button in x seconds). When there's a quick time event I want to show the button that has to be pressed and the time left to press that button.

I play the movie(s) using an AVPlayerView. On top of that AVPlayerView I have placed a label. But the label is always invisible. It's because of the AVPlayerView.

So does anyone know a way around this?

**Edit**

I didn't use any code to place the label on top of the AVPlayerView. I just placed it there in the MainMenu.xib. When I view it in Xcode it looks like this:

[image: Screenshot in Xcode]

But when I run the application it looks like this:

[image: Screenshot in Xcode]

As you can see in the first image, all objects are under "View" and the label appears lower in the list so it should be on top of the AVPlayerView. Xcode displays the label on top of the AVPlayerView (image 1), but when I run the application the label is underneath the AVPlayerView (image 2). So my question was how to display the label on top of the AVPlayerView.

I hope this is enough information ;)

Comment: Question: How do you put the label on top of the view?  Suggestion: Try using Xcode's view capture feature to examine the position, size, and z-order of your views while the application is running.

Comment: @PhillipMills I can't see the label there

Comment: Well, that leads back to my question then.

Comment: @PhilipMills How I put in on top of the view? I just dragged a label onto the view in the MainMenu.xib. I can see the label in Xcode but not in the application.

Comment: Have you switched the player and label to beibg layer-backed?

Comment: "On top of that AVPlayerView I have placed a label. But the label is always invisible."  Nobody but you sees it since you don't even show a single line of code.

Comment: If u drag the label onto the view, the label will be a child of the view. hence your layer will cover up the label. what you need to do is put the label above the view.

Comment: @ElTomato I didn't use any code. That's why I didn't even show a single line of code. I have added screenshots to show the problem.

Comment: try superView.bringSubviewToFron(subview)

Comment: @scord It says "Property 'bringSubviewToFront' not found on object of type 'NSView *' "

Comment: I just tried this: new Cocoa project (non-storyboard); drag a AVPlayerView onto the default window. Drag a Label onto the default window, increase font size and colour red, partially overlap the player view. The label renders on top of the player in both Xcode and the debugged application. So there seems to be something else at play here. Did you try this simple test in a new, blank Cocoa application to try and isolate the issue?

Comment: @TheNextman That did work actually. But I didn't do anything different this time. I only made a new project. I'm sure this is a clue, but I don't know what's causing this.

Comment: @Developer There must be a difference :) If you find it, you answer your question..

Answer (score 0):

Link your label to an IBOutlet in the ViewController which describes your view and in the viewDidLoad() method write

```
/*top of your file*/
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
/* other properties */

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    /*code*/

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:myLabel]; 
}

/*rest of your code*/
```

This should do the trick for you.